# Why grab the <body> during a click event? using .on() instead of .click()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

How come the second code better than the first? Why not grab the `.vote a` directly, instead of grabbing the `body` tag? I'm creating a voting system using AJAX/JSON/PHP:

```
$('.vote a').click(function() {});

$('body').on('click','.vote a',function(){});
```

Comment: Read about event delegation

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second example is a delegated event handler. It is attaching the `click` event to the body so that it can be applied to any `.vote a` element which are appended to the DOM after the page has loaded.

You may also see a performance increase from using the delegated model even when there are no elements appended after DOMReady, if there are a lot of elements you need to attach the same event handler to.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of doing is called as [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). And that would be useful when binding events for the elements which are created at run time(dynamically).